# How to get an iframe to render in pug from a json payload?

Tags: node.js, express, iframe, pug

The problem is my iframe is being rendered displayed as text instead of an iframe. Here is he payload

```
 var payload = {
  'iat': now,
  'nbf': now,
  'exp': now + 86400, //one day from now.
  'dashboard': 224277,
  'organization': 19190,
  'env': {"MYVAR": 42}
};

var token = jwt.encode(payload, ORGANIZATION_SECRET, 'HS256');
var src = 'iframe#dash.embedf(src=\'' + BASE_URL + '/' + token + '\')';
console.log(src);
res.render("pages/sponsorship", {frame: src});
});
```

This is the pug template, sponsorship.

```
#container
  .row
    #chart-container

include ../../partials/footer

  script
    | var src  = !{JSON.stringify(frame)}
    | document.getElementById('chart-container').innerHTML = (src);
```

The output in browser is raw text instead of rending the iframe.

[pic of output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za8nk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking the browser to compile pug code, which it doesn't do. Instead, change the `src` variable to use standard html:

```
var payload = {
  'iat': now,
  'nbf': now,
  'exp': now + 86400, //one day from now.
  'dashboard': 224277,
  'organization': 19190,
  'env': {"MYVAR": 42}
};

var token = jwt.encode(payload, ORGANIZATION_SECRET, 'HS256');
var src = '<iframe id="dash" class="embedf" src="' + BASE_URL + '/' + token + '"></iframe>';
console.log(src);
res.render("pages/sponsorship", {frame: src});
});
```

Comment: It works. thanks! I thought pug would render the pug code into HTML for the browser?

Comment: To pug, it's just a variable containing a string. The script where you set the inner html of an element doesn't run until the page loads in a browser.